# Escaping variables when using open 'smb://$LOGIN:$PASSWORD@$SERVER/$PATH'

Tags: terminal, smb

I'm trying to connect to a server using variables. However I get it to use the variables instead of the variable name. 
So far I've tried:

```
/usr/bin/open 'smb://"$LOGIN":"$PASSWORD"@"$SERVER"/"$PATH"'
/usr/bin/open 'smb://$LOGIN:$PASSWORD@$SERVER/$PATH'
/usr/bin/open 'smb://\$LOGIN:\$PASSWORD@\$SERVER/\$PATH'
/usr/bin/open smb://$LOGIN:$PASSWORD@$SERVER/$PATH
/usr/bin/open 'smb://\'$LOGIN':\'$PASSWORD'@\'$SERVER'/\'$PATH''
/usr/bin/open 'smb://"$LOGIN:$PASSWORD@$SERVER/$PATH"'
```

Comment: You need double-quotes around the whole thing, no single-quotes anywhere, percent-encoding of any funny characters (esp. in the password), and lower- or mixed-case variable names to avoid conflicts with the all-caps names with special functions (like `$PATH`).

Comment: So you want to use the values stores in the variables fornthe connection? Can you show us the errors you get (some are probably obvious, but at least one line should actually work)? Also, PATH has a special meaning to the shell, are you really using this?